# Caching singleton in memcache

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, jdo, datanucleus

I am developing in Google App Engine since one year ago and I am understanding how important is the warmup time for instances.
So I ended up with an idea: is it possible to cache singleton in memcache? For example I am using the singleton pattern for JDO PersistenceManagerFactory.

Here is my actual code (as described in documentation):

```
    private static PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(<my-name>);
```

Does it have any sense something like extend the JDOHelper and write a function like this one:

```
public static PersistenceManagerFactory getPersistenceManagerFactoryCached(String name) {
    MemcacheService cache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();;
    PersistenceManagerFactory staticPMF= null;
    if (cache.contains("JDO_PMF")) {
        staticPMF = (PersistenceManagerFactory) cache.get("JDO_PMF");
    } else {
        staticPMF = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(name);
        cache.put("JDO_PMF", staticPMF);
    }
    return staticPMF;
}
```

My idea should be to cache the PersistenceManagerFactory to speed-up the first instance and then use this one as the singleton:

```
private static PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelperCached.getPersistenceManagerFactory(<my-name>);
```

Comment: If you're worried about overhead, stop using JDO. The PMF has to load a whole bunch of data that's really irrelevant to your app - using something better suited to the task, like Objectify, will avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just found this link, seems different instances cannot share PersistenceManagerFactory instance according to Ikai Lan at https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/1b90fae408b52d49

==========================================================================

I like the idea, and I have tried straight away on my code, but unfortunately I got some error like this:

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: No available StoreManager found for the datastore URL key "". Please make sure you have all relevant plugins in the CLASSPATH (e.g datanucleus-rdbms?, datanucleus-db4o?), and consider setting the persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType" to the type of store you are using e.g rdbms, db4o
```

Maybe it's only my issue but I can't tell at this stage.

I have thought about this more:

So let's assume the way you suggest is working and you can get the right factory you need. The real performance will depend on how you use your memcache.

1) If you have a lot of write in your memcache, then that means potentially the PersistenceManagerFactory may be kicked out of the cache frequently, which means you need to create it again.

2) Every time you create a new PersistenceManagerFactory, you will put in into the cache which according to my experience dealing with GAE is pretty unstable and sometimes the put in part can take much longer than you expected.

Comment: uhm .. I don't completely agree, probably I am missing something .. From my point of view it is always a singleton in each instance of GAE. So it just works better than before. Because the "worst case scenario" of this case (no JDO_PMF in memcache) is the common scenario for the normal class: for each warmup request it creates a new JDO singleton

Comment: I don't think each instance of GAE will have a singleton, because memcache service is shared by all instances.

Comment: well ok, in this case I agree .. It depends on what we call "singleton": I mean only there will be one instance of the class PersistenceManagerFactory for each GAE instance .. For sure it is cached in memcache, but each JVM that runs on each GAE instance has its own PersistenceManagerFactory. Do you agree that in any case it is better than the normal approach?

Comment: From different instances of gae you will get different instances of PersistenceManagerFactory. Don't think this will work. Do you try to run your example? Beter create permanent frontend or even backend that will not be shout down.